# Best practice for Samba file permissions: To use nobody.nogroup or not?

Tags: permissions, samba

I have been running a samba file server with multiple shares, multiple users and different Samba-level permissions (i.e. write list, read list). The way I set it up on the file system is to change ownership of all the shared files and directories to nobody.nogroup. In my smb.conf, for every one of the Samba shares, I used

```
force user = nobody
force group = nogroup
```

This way, I delegate the control of the permissions to the Samba layer. It's not pretty but this was how I got it to work back in Ubuntu 12.04. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and re-visited my Samba configuration. Using nobody.nogroup at the filesystem level seems to defeat the purpose of filesystem security. I was wondering what is the best practice for filesystem-level permissioning in my setup.

Comment: "Using nobody.nogroup at the filesystem level seems to defeat the purpose of filesystem security." What makes you think that?

Comment: Isn't that coarse-graining the permissions at the system level? I am curious what sort of solutions others are employing.

Comment: I'd think that would only matter if users have direct access to the filesystem. It seems to me that your users access it only through samba, and the filesystem could well have been a trivial object store without anybody noticing the difference. That's to say: do the filesystem permissions matter in way to anybody?

Comment: That's true. But what would be the best practice if filesystem fine permission control is required for different groups of users? That is something that is missing from the online tutorials and manuals.

Comment: Use ACLs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs